# Create One Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-ui

I have the following code which is triggered using JQuery.UI.Sortable and it is behaving unexpectedly.

I need to create one array of objects in this function and return it every time it is called.

```
function saveOrder(el) {
    var slideOrder = new Array();
    $(el).each(function() {
        var slideId = $(this).attr("data-llp-slide-id"),
            slideNo = $(this).attr("data-llp-slide-number"),
            slideOb = {slideId,slideNo};
        slideOrder.push(slideOb);
    });
    return slideOrder;
}
```

What I am getting is multiple objects/arrays returned

Code that is triggering the function above as requested by @Rhumborl

```
function init() {
    $('.slide-list').sortable({
        connectWith: ".connected-sortable",
        stack: '.connected-sortable ul',
        stop: function(e){
            $(".slide-item").each(function(i, el){
                var hash = $(el).index()+1;
                $(el).attr('data-llp-slide-number',hash);
                $(el).find('[data-llp-slide-number-display]').text(hash);
                var newOrder = saveOrder(el);
                console.debug(newOrder);
            });
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

Comment: @BharathvajGanesan ArrayObject is in PHP, not JavaScript

Comment: @Rhumborl thanks for the clarification, are you able to answer?

Comment: Is there any arrayofobjects tags @Rhumborl?

Comment: @JustinErswell what exactly is triggering the method? Is it a particular event in Sortable?

Comment: @Rhumborl updated the question to answer your query

Comment: Have you debugged to check if the function is only called one time? Most likely the event is being fired more than once and therefore the function being requested multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the context you mentioned it is invalid object in the javascript. And you couldn't push like this

```
slideOb = {slideId,slideNo};
slideOrder.push(slideOb);
```

First define slideOb is an valid object then push like below

```
  slideOb = {'id': slideId, 'no':slideNo};
  slideOrder.push(slideOb);
```

Now slideOrder is an local array it is always hold one array object. make it as global to push more arrays into it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, however, I am defining the Array inside the function should it be defined outside of the function?

Comment: var slideOrder = new Array(); remove it in the function add top of the js

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is that every time the ```.slide-item``` is moved I get an array with all of the items in the UL with their slide ID and Number so that I can post this via AJAX to update a database table